# #ifdefs in .cpp and .h files

Tags: c++, compilation

This is a noob question .

Basically I have `.h` & `.cpp` file  I need to introduce conditional compilation via `#ifdef` into it. Both the `.h` and `.cpp` contain 10 functions. I need to do conditional compilation for only 2 of them. Hence I was going to wrap the 2 in the `.h` file within `#ifdef`'s

Question 1: Do I need to again wrap the function implementation in C++ files as well? I guess not, right? I want to be sure.

Question 2: I have an array of function pointers of these 10 functions. Should I wrap `#ifdef` inside this array for the 2 functions as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: If they are class function, yes. Otherwise you might be ok if you don't ifdef them but I personally would. Because if someone declares the function as extern in another translation unit, he just gained access to the function.

2: I wouldn't do it because it would cause all the clients to handle 2 different size of array. I would only set those 2 pointers to NULL and handle that case on the caller side.

Comment: yes you are right about 1 and 2 . For 2 i found a good solution . For 2 i will have a #ifdef platform check and implement dummy functions in non compatible platforms that just return error . In that way the structure will still remain the same :-)

Comment: Sure this also work great, I do that all the time for cross platform code.